LaTeX3 programming layer documentation on website not working
The LaTeX3 programming layer documentation on website is not working.  Could this be fixed ?
The LaTeX3 programming layer (which is part of the LaTeX format) is documented in

    The L3 programming layer interface documentation

The source documentation for L3 is also not working.
It would be helpful if some details are added in the help documentation page itself the relevant calls to texdoc.
Which would also assist users who happen to encounter a problem accessing the help pages when something as described happens.
Source code documentation

The full documentation of the source code with all commands and their implementation can be obtained by processing source2e.tex distributed as part of the LaTeX2e distribution. A compiled version (from the current release) with a list of all major changes and an index of all commands and their usage within the kernel is

    The LaTeX2e Sources (1000+ pages)
    The L3 programming layer sources (1000+ pages)


... on website is not working: Which website? Unless the answer is TeX SE, why are you telling us?

The problem is the LaTeX project site, it has a link into ctan and there the l3kernel moved under required while in the past in was under contrib. I'll fix.
Should be corrected by now.

Could you add information on how to get the same information using other means (e.g. texdoc) in the help section in addition to the links ?
